# Evaluate string as formula in cell in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, eval, excel-formula

I haven't had any luck finding an eval-type function to use in a cell for Excel.

Let's say I have a cell A1 that contains string "C4". I'd like to be able to write an in-cell function similar to this `IF(EVAL(A1)>10,"TOO BIG","TOO SMALL")`. That would then effectively be C4>10 for the expression.

Is this possible without VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem the solution would be:

```
IF(INDIRECT(A1)>10,"TOO BIG","TOO SMALL")
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using an add-in that supplies EVAL? See my comment below...

Comment: The problem is that I have to translate because I do not have an english localized excel available (I am italian). So I do not remember why I added EVAL which is unnecessary; I have edited to correct

Comment: Sorry, I had not thought about international differences before commenting...is the worksheet function named INDIRECT in English-language Excel named EVAL in Italian-language Excel?

Comment: It was my mistake. EVAL is used by mouche and I did not edited out. I edited my answer, now should be correct, try it.